# external package from go get

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-api-go-client

I want use `code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2` and other.

My app is structured like:

```
+-- MyApp
+---- app.yaml
+---- main.go
+---- src/
+------ ...external package...
```

My GOPATH is equal to "MyApp/src"

In my main.go I have `// +build !appengine"

I can't launch `goapp serve`, I get

```
2014/12/09 22:20:32 Can't find package "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/googleapi" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/googleapi" in any of:
```

and many other who said the same.

How I can use package download from a `go get`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a gopath looks like this: (I have added random projects to it to demonstrate what it could look like)

- gopath

  - src

    - code.google.com

      - p

        - google-api-go-client

          - etc
    - github.com

      - fluffle

        - goirc
    - rohan.com  <- **This is where your own projects go(or in code.google.com or github.com)**

      - my_random_project

        - main.go
        - helper.go
      - my_app_engine_project

        - app

          - app.yaml
          - my_app_engine_project.go
        - routes

          - random_rest_route.go
        - process

          - random_route_logic.go
  - pkg
  - bin

Your $GOPATH$ enviroment variable should point to that root folder which contains src, pkg and bin.

So when you **go get** a package from github for example it'l be put in the github.com src folder, and that's when you'll be able to use that library in your own projects.

***Usage Example***

So for example, if I need the fluffle/goirc library from github, I'l type:

```
go get github.com/fluffle/goirc
```

The library will then be placed in:

```
gopath/src/github.com
```

And I can use the library by importing it with:

```
import (
     "github.com/fluffle/goirc/client"
)
```

And then use it

```
client.NewConfig("My User Name")
```